# How can I parse the output of `ps` to different fields?

Tags: ps

I would like to parse the output of `ps`, to get any field using `awk`. It seems that `ps` separate the fields by whitespaces, but  the values in `COMMAND` field usually have whitespaces.

Is there a way to tell `ps` to use some distinctive field separator in its output? I haven't found one in `ps` manpage.

If not, what can I do to get the values in a field? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can explicitly specify your own field separator in the format string argument when utilizing a **printf()** style user-defined output:

```
$ ps -o '%p,%a,%c,%y'
  PID,COMMAND                    ,COMMAND        ,TTY
15742,ps -o %p,%a,%c,%y          ,ps             ,pts/6
24719,-su                        ,bash           ,pts/6
```

Comment: This is version-specific. If you're on MacOS (Darwin), the `%x`s aren't available.

Answer (score 1):

You can first replace multiple spaces with a single space (or any other character). See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19014/how-to-strip-multiple-spaces-to-one-using-sed) on how to accomplish this. Next you can use `cut` to select the column(s) you want. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629908/bash-split-output-of-command-by-columns).

Comment: Thanks. Does ps always separate two fields by more than one whitespaces? Does a value under `COMMAND` never contain more than one consecutive whitespaces?

Comment: Not sure about that one.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the fact that a shell `read` places ALL residual fields into the last variable, and print COMMAND last.

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,tty,args | while read PID CMD TTY ARG; do echo $PID $CMD $TTY $ARG; done
```

You can convey `$ARG` to `awk`, or else concatenate `$4` ... `$NF` within `awk` when reading the `ps` output directly

Answer (score 1):

You can pad everything to the max, and then treat "lots of spaces" as the separator ...and change that to pipe or some other caracter to be a bit more sane. Here's a `--format` that does what `-f` normally does, plus changing the separator, and adding "label" (what `-Z` normally does) which is another field that can have spaces, showing that simply moving those to the end is not enough.

```
ps -e --format "label:200 uid:200 pid:200 ppid:200 c:200 stime:200 tty:200 time:200 command:200" \
    | sed -r 's| {100,}|\||g'
```

But maybe this can have side effects... the limit ps will allow for padding on my machine seems to be between 100 and 200 spaces; maybe it's different somewhere else. And maybe a command has that many spaces in it. There is no guarantee this will always work. If you need a guarantee (like in an unattended script), you basically have to reimplement ps, like look in `/proc/[0-9]*` to collect all this information yourself.